# REST service Google Analytics integration

Tags: python, django, google-analytics, django-rest-framework

I have a REST service implemented using django-rest-framework. What I would like to do is start recording Google Analytics data (events for starters) when particular requests are made.

I've done some looking around, I see there is a [Google Analytics python library](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/apis/analytics/v3?hl=en) , but from what I can see it's more for querying the API and not posting to it. I see there is a [py-ga](https://github.com/kra3/py-ga-mob/) library but it hasn't been updated in awhile. Seems other libraries for django and analytics are meant to be used client side via JavaScript.

What would be a reasonable way to implement what I am looking for? Am I missing an official library somewhere? Anyone have any experience doing this? Any advice would be appreciated, thanks much!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are set on using Google Analytics, you could look into using the [measurement protocol](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/devguide) (covered in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9503329/is-there-any-way-to-post-events-to-google-analytics-via-server-side-api)) with an http library like [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/). It would end up looking like something along these lines

```
import requests
payload = 'v=1&t=event&tid=UA-XXXXXY&cid=555&ec=video&ea=play&el=holiday&ev=300'
r = requests.post('http://www.google-analytics.com/collect', data=payload)
```